# Timeout error when creating an image in Google Cloud from a .vmdk file

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to create an image in Google Cloud from a .vmdk file, the process does not finish, sending a timeout error after 23hrs 57 min of execution, this is the command I enter.

gcloud compute images import activedirectory --os=windows-2016 --network=vpc-papelsanfrancisco  --subnet=subnet
1 --timeout=24h --source-file="gs://imagenes_servidores-no-sap/ActiveDirectory/VMPSFDC_Disk1_Mon--24-Aug-2020-at-14-16-17-(UTC--07-00)-flat.vmdk"

Any idea why this is happening?

-------------------------------------------------This is the error ----------------------------
[import-image.translate-image]: 2020-08-27T15:20:22Z Step "wait-for-translate" (WaitForInstancesSignal) timed-out.
[import-image]: 2020-08-27T15:20:22Z Error running workflow: step "translate-image" run error: Step "wait-for-translate" (WaitForInstancesSignal) timed-out.
[import-image]: 2020-08-27T15:20:22Z Workflow "import-image" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[import-image]: 2020-08-27T15:22:38Z Workflow "import-image" finished cleanup.
[import-image]: 2020-08-27T15:22:39.662Z Import did not complete within the specified timeout of 23h55m0s
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share with you some recommendations that worked for me:

Make sure that the cloud build service account of that project has Storage Object Viewer and Editor roles on the bucket or on the object `gs://imagenes_servidores-no-sap/ActiveDirectory/VMPSFDC_Disk1_Mon--24-Aug-2020-at-14-16-17-(UTC--07-00)-flat.vmdk`

1. Open Cloud Console and navigate to IAM & Admin > IAM
2. Locate the Cloud Build service account `xxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`
3. Click on the corresponding pencil icon to edit the current roles
4. Add the Storage Object Viewer and Editor roles.

If you want to add a more restricted role, then you can try roles/compute.networkUser instead of Editor for the same service account.

You can get more information about the permissions needed in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#permissions)

I would also recommend specifying the `--project` flag for the destination of the import, in case this value is set to something else in your cloud sdk.

If your disk is using UEFI, you can import virtual disks with an UEFI bootloader by using the Cloud Build API and specifying the `-uefi_compatible` argument. Please check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#importing_a_virtual_disk_with_uefi_bootloader) for further information.

Also please check the [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#limitations) section.

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuestad Jose Luis, agregué los roles y verifiqué la limitación y todo está bien, vuelvo a ejecutar el proceso y sigo teniendo el mismo problema, el proceso no termina, enviando un error de timeout después de 23hrs 57 min de ejecución. El tipo de disco configurado en la VM es BIOS.

Comment: I can't see any special configuration for BootFirmware BIOS, but it seems that your disk could be too big, have you tried a longer timeout? if not, you could try with something like 48 hrs or the time you consider. 
Additionally you can try to use the flag `--log-http` in order to get more information about the error.
On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guide on [comments written in non-English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/14004844) and [Non-English Question Policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy)